# Is $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{N}(x, \Sigma), cI) = \mathcal{N}(x, \Sigma + cI)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Is a multi-variate normal distribution with the mean defined by a normal distribution again a normal distribution where the covariance matrices are summed up?

That is, is
$\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{N}(x, \Sigma), cI) = \mathcal{N}(x, \Sigma + cI)$?

Or more general, is
$\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{N}(x, A), B) = \mathcal{N}(x, A+B)$?

Comment: If you work in context of bayesian estimation then you imply that "inner" normal distrituion is independent of outer one. It so, then angryavian's answer works. Or you should write what type of dependence do you imply - otherwise it's not possible to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you recognize that $\mathcal{N}(\mu, B)$ has the same distribution as $\mu + Z$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, B)$, then it seems that you are asking for the distribution of $Z+X$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(x, A)$ and where $Z$ and $X$ are independent. (Otherwise, you should clarify what $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{N}(x, A), B)$ means.)

Then $Z+X$ is jointly normal, as it is the sum of two independent Gaussian vectors. Its mean is $E[Z+X] = E[Z] + E[X] = x$ and its covariance is $A+B$ because
$$\text{Cov}(Z_i + X_i, Z_j + X_j)
= \text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) + \text{Cov}(Z_i, Z_j) = A_{i,j} + B_{i,j}.$$